# How can I create two id tags from this script?

Tags: html, css, button, css-transitions

I want to make it so that I can have multiple buttons opening their own transition. As of now I have this code which works fine, however, if I repeat it or even change the css (class) to match an individual button, the primary button will still open the secondary transition and the newly placed secondary button remains inactive.

**CSS**

```
<style>
body, 
.container, 
.content-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    background: #fff;
}

.menu-wrap a {
    color: #b8b7ad;
}

.menu-wrap a:hover,
.menu-wrap a:focus {
    color: #c94e50;
}

.content-wrap {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    overflow-y: visible;
}

.content::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: none;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0s 0.4s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s, transform 0s 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

/* Menu Button 1 */
.menu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    text-indent: 2.5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 1;

    top: 510px;
    left: 855px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */     -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */     
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.menu-button::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5em;
    right: 0.2em;
    bottom: 0.4em;
    left: -1px;
    background: linear-gradient(#929292 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 40%, #929292 40%, #929292 58%, transparent 0%, transparent 80%, #929292 80%);
    content: '';
}


.menu-button:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Close Button */
.close-button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    top: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 1em;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
        opacity: 0;

}

.close-button::before,
.close-button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 3px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    background: #bdc3c7;
}

.close-button::before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close-button::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/* Comments */
.menu-wrap {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
width: 429.0500011444092px;
height: 600.875px;
right: 0;
background: #0C0C0C;
top: 6px;
padding: 0;
font-size: 1.15em;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(500px,0,0);
transform: translate3d(500px,0,0);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
transition: transform 0.4s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.menu, 
.icon-list {
    height: 100%;
}

.icon-list {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}

.icon-list a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.8em;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,500px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,500px,0);
}

.icon-list,
.icon-list a {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0s 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0s 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1000px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,1000px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1500px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,1500px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,2000px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,2000px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,2500px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,2500px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,3000px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,3000px,0);
}

.icon-list a span {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* Shown menu */
.show-menu .menu-wrap {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.show-menu .icon-list,
.show-menu .icon-list a {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.show-menu .icon-list a {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.9s;
    transition-duration: 0.9s;
}

.show-menu .content::before {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s;
    transition: opacity 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}</style>
```

**BEING TRANSITIONED**

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
</div>
```

**BUTTON**

```
<button class="menu-button" id="open-button">Open Menu</button>
```

**DEMO**

[*DEMO*](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNvobY)

As you can see if you scroll towards the middle of the demo result window you will see the first button opening both transitions while the second button does nothing, I want the second button to open the bottom transition on its own.

Comment: Could you provide us with a demo because, as it stands, it's not clear what the actual issue is?

Comment: Sorry, I just provided a demo. Please go ahead and check it out, thanks.

Comment: Demo doesn't seem to do *anything*...at least it's not obvious to me.

Comment: Scroll down, the three dots are the buttons. Click it.

Comment: Click the first one and you'll see that it opens two black boxes, I only want the first button (three dots) to open the first transition (black box) and the second button (three dots) to open the second transition (black box).

Comment: Both of your buttons have the same ID. They definitely shouldn't..

Comment: Yes I tried changing the ID, as I said above, but still no effect.

Comment: Right now you are toggling the class show-menu on body. And when body gets the class show-menu, all descendants of show-menu with the class menu-wrap are transformed. So both menus open. And only the first button works because you use the same ID on both and when you call getelementbyid, you will get the first button and never the second.

Comment: Sofor starters, you should give each button a unique id and each should have their own click event, i.e. toggleMenuOne and toggleMenuTwo. Each of these functions should then apply specific css for the correct menu-wrap.. =)

Comment: I get changing the class, but how do I assign different id's with this script?